Script to move a row from one sheet to another based on dropdown status
I found the following script that moves a row from my "Active" sheet to my "Done" sheet in the same workbook when I change the status.
The issue with this script is that if I change the status to anything it moves it.
The result I want is that the row only moves if the status is changed to "Done"
I also would love it if I can move it back to the "Active" sheet if I change the status to anything but the Done status.
Made a copy of my sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rBKv_r4eKz0kpkeiv55MRo0X0m4LE0JwBTKp2xdTLoo/edit?usp=sharing
function onEdit(e) {                
const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();              
const r = e.range;              
if (src.getName() != "Active" || r.columnStart != 5 || r.rowStart == 1) return;             
const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Done");              
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12));              
src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);              
}               


To add a test for the value entered in the cell, refer to e.value, like this:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 5 || e.range.rowStart === 1) return;
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  let targetSheet;
  if (sheetName === 'Active') {
    if (e.value !== 'Done') return;
    targetSheetName = 'Done';
  } else if (sheetName === 'Done') {
    targetSheetName = 'Active';
  } else {
    return;
  }
  targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 12)
    .moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  e.source.toast(`Moved row ${e.range.rowStart} to sheet '${targetSheetName}'.`);
}

Also see these onEdit(e) optimization tips.
